# Complex field-level permissions in MongoDB Realm and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, mongodb, swiftui, permissions, realm

I am using the MongoDB Realm Swift SDK and app backend. I am using the `@ObservedResults` property wrapper to access Realm objects in my views.

I need to set permissions for a collaborative document called `Procedure`. This is created by the owner, who can invite another user (a *supervisor*) to comment on it and sign it off.

Only the supervisor can write their response, and only the owner can write the other fields, though each should be able to read the other’s (with the exception of *private notes*, which should be invisible to the supervisor).

I have made comments about permissions in the class definition below.

```
class Procedure: Object {

    // ID
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId

    // Owner (this is unique per user)
    @Persisted var ownerID: String

    // Read/write by owner. Read by supervisor.
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var body: String

    // Private notes - Read/write by owner, invisible to supervisor
    @Persisted var privateNotes: String

    // Supervisor - this is the user ID of the supervisor
    @Persisted var supervisorID: String?

    // Supervisor response - Read/write by supervisor. Read by owner
    @Persisted var supervisorResponse: String?
}

extension Procedure: Identifiable {
    
    var id: String {
        self._id.stringValue
    }
}
```

I am using *Flexible Sync* and have tried setting the following permission document.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Procedure": [
      {
        "name": "supervisor_restricted_read",
        "applyWhen": {
          "supervisorID": "%%user.id"
        },
        "fields": {
          "privateNotes": {
            "read": false,
            "write": false
          }
        },
        "additional_fields": {
          "read": true,
          "write": false
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "owner_read_write",
        "applyWhen": {},
        "read": {
          "ownerID": "%%user.id"
        },
        "write": {
          "ownerID": "%%user.id"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "defaultRoles": []
}
```

However, with these permissions, I still only get `Procedure` instances that match on `ownerID` in `@ObservedResults` (not where the `supervisorID` matches the current users ID).

I assume I am using permissions incorrectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further reading of the docs, a user can only have one session role at a time. As a user can be both and owner and supervisor (of different documents), I tried rolling the permissions into a single role, with a *OR* predicate, which seems to work!

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Procedure": [
      {
        "name": "owner_supervisor_procedure_permission",
        "applyWhen": {},
        "read": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "ownerID": "%%user.id"
            },
            {
              "supervisorID": "%%user.id"
            }
          ]
        },
        "write": {
          "ownerID": "%%user.id"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "defaultRoles": [
    {
      "name": "owner-read-write",
      "applyWhen": {},
      "read": {
        "ownerID": "%%user.id"
      },
      "write": {
        "ownerID": "%%user.id"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```